# Fussing instead of microphone sound

Tags: sound, lenovo, microphone

I just switched from Windows to Ubuntu, and everything works fine, until my friend called me. He told me he can't hear me and  [discord](https://discord.com/)  reports it doesn't detect input.

I went to the settings and selected the first and now he hears fussing, very, very loud fussing, just like  someone blowing on a cheap microphone when you have your speakers at max, that's how it sounded.  BTW, I'm on a [Lenovo Ideapad 320-17ikb][2] model 80xm.

Ubuntu version is 20.04 (the latest lts) and i use the incorporated microphone...

How do I troubleshoot this?